# How to increase pH in a cocktail?

Tags: cocktails, mixers

I've recently become fascinated by the use of butterfly pea blossoms to add colour to alcoholic drinks. (Yes, I've been watching How To Drink on YouTube). It acts as a natural pH indicator--add lemon juice to blossom-infused gin, and it'll go from purplish-blue to pink.

The thing is, for Reasons, I want to do the reverse! I'd like to make a slightly acidic beverage, then raise the pH, so it turns purple in the glass.

I'm familiar with using e.g. bicarb to raise pH in savoury cooking--for caramelizing onions, that sort of thing. But I'm concerned about the flavour effects on an alcoholic drink. Are there any edible ways to raise pH that are flavourless, or would be easily masked by a cocktail?

If there aren't, would an Alka-Seltzer tablet provide the right pH reaction? I'm not a chemistry person at all so I'm not sure if the acid-base reaction would provide colour change as well as the bubbles.

TLDR what I want to do is dye a spirit with butterfly pea blossom, add acid to turn it pink, then at the moment of service add (ideally flavourless) ____________ to turn it purple/blue again.

Thanks in advance, all!

Comment: Answered over in Cooking, apparently what I want is calcium hydroxide.

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged across SE and should be avoided. That said, you've already posted on here and it is an interesting question. Maybe add your comment as an answer below, link to the post of Cooking and then accept your own answer so people don't click on the post thinking it still needs answering

Comment: Related: [How to add alkaline to a drink?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100441/how-to-add-alkaline-to-a-drink)

Comment: Try using simple sugar, sugar water or syrup. It should work.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it has an answer on [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/100441/how-to-add-alkaline-to-a-drink).